# BERT( Bidirectional Encoder Representations from Transformers) with numbers

Tags: python, nlp

*Hi!*

I am trying to understand how BERT is dealing with text that has number within. 
More concretely I'm trying to find the most similar line in document(text+numbers) and specific line(text+numbers).

I tried an example with BERT of 30 characters and cosine similarity:

```
sentence2 = "I have 2 apple"; score(between sentence1 & sentence2): 0.99000436
sentence3 = "I have 3 apple"; score(between sentence1 & sentence3): 0.98602057
sentence4 = "I have 0 apple"; score(between sentence1 & sentence4): 0.97923964
sentence5 = "I have 2.1 apple"; score(between sentence1 & sentence5): 0.95482975
```

I do not understand why sentence4 has smaller score than sentence3(0 closer to 1 than 3), and 2.1 is closer to 1 than 3...

Comment: Please provide your code to show what you have tried to so far.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing is that you are probably kind of confusing the model by having the apples in the singular.

BERT is primarily a language model. It does interpret sentences using predicate logic, it models how language is used. The use of language is the only training signal it has. *"I have 2 apples."* and *"I have 3 apples."* are both pretty natural sentences, the only difference is the number.

On the other hand, *"I have 2.1 apples."* is a very unusual sentence. People don't express the quantity of apples using floating-point numbers. This is not how language is usually used which makes it different from the first two sentences.

Answer (score 0):

Language models including BERT are trained to fit the predictability of tokens in strings. Therefore, the learned representation is not going to have the expected properties of numbers. After all, this is not a simple task if you consider different units, packages and etc which can affect how we should evaluate numbers. I recommend this paper for more discussion and research on this topic:

> Spithourakis, G., & Riedel, S. (2018, July). Numeracy for Language Models: Evaluating and Improving their Ability to Predict Numbers. In Proceedings of the 56th Annual Meeting of the Association for Computational Linguistics (Volume 1: Long Papers) (pp. 2104-2115).
>   [paper](https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/P18-1196/); 
>   [code repository](https://github.com/uclnlp/numerate-language-models);